# How to create liquibase changeset for integration tests in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, liquibase, integration-testing

I want mock data for integration tests by liquibase changeset, how to make that to not affect real database? I found partial idea from [here](https://tillias.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/unit-testing-and-integration-testing-using-junit-liquibase-hsqldb-hibernate-maven-and-spring-framework/), but I am using springboot and I hope there is simpler solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use liquibase's context parameter. For example create changeset which will have inserts loaded from sql file and specify the context for it. Something like this:

```
<changeSet id="test_data_inserts" author="me" context="test">
    <sqlFile path="test_data.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>
```

and in spring boot's `application.properties` for test specify the property `liquibase.contexts=test`.

Comment: This solution doesn't allow to keep artifacts related to testing in a separate file & folder which is not good. I would like to have a separate liquibase file which will be virtually merged into main liquibase file when running tests.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. You can have separate changelog for tests and include whatever you want in there.

Comment: The reason is simple: I don't want files being a part of application binary which is going to run on production to be messed by artifacts related to tests (unit tests, integration tests, etc.).

Comment: create a question for that and I can help you with it.

Comment: Actually I found the solution in meantime: application properties file for tests should override liquibase file name, there should be a liquibase file in folder 'test/resources' which should include liquibase file from 'main/resources' and it can contain some change-sets for inserting data for tests.

Comment: @KrzysztofTomaszewski maybe you could write your solution of linking the yaml changelog from main/resources in test/resources, cause i have the same issue now. It would be very helpful

Comment: Yes, please @KrzysztofTomaszewski share your solution. I'm with the same need as you

Comment: Here is the suggestion from Liquibase, using contexts : https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/contexts.html#using-contexts-for-test-data. However be careful to exclude it in production, with `contexts=!test`. It's easy to make mistakes...

Comment: Otherwise, you can use _labels_ to have a different behaviour than with _contexts_, maybe less prone to errors. See : https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/labels.html.

Comment: In fact, if a label is not specified, then **ALL labels** will be executed. So you have to specify `--labels=""` to have a different behaviour...

Answer (score 13):

Assume production changeset placed inside resources/db/changelog/changes, and there is a db.changelog-master.yaml in /db/changelog with following config

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/changes
```

Place the testing changset inside test/resources/db/changelog/testchanges and create
db.changelog-master.yaml in test/resources/db/changelog with following config

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/changes
  - includeAll:
      path: db/changelog/testchanges
```

The test should pick up all changeset in two paths and run

Comment: It works but be careful, all migrations from _changes_ well be executed, **then** those inside _testchanges_. Which can be a problem on the long term. If a script from _testchanges_ must be executed before a script from _changes_, it doesn't seem to be possible. See doc : https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/includeall.html

Answer (score 0):

Using final solution by @Krzysztof Tomaszewski

> application properties file for tests should override liquibase file name, there should be a liquibase file in folder 'test/resources' which should include liquibase file from 'main/resources' and it can contain some change-sets for inserting data for tests.

I ended up with following configuration:

```
  change-log: "classpath:db/liquibase-changelog-test.xml" //(1)
  search-path: "./src/test/resources,./src/main/resources" //(2)
```

(1) rewrite [change-log file property](https://docs.liquibase.com/parameters/changelog-file.html)
(2) rewrite [search-path property](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/how-liquibase-finds-files.html)

and `liquibase-changelog-test.xml` looks like this:

```
<include file="db/liquibase-changelog.xml"/> //changelog file in /src/main/resources  (creating schema etc.)
<include file="changes/01-insert-data.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/> //changes file in /src/test/resources/db, file is relative to liquibase-changelog-test.xml file (inserting data for tests)
```