# Ensure test data separation from production - liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, liquibase

Following [How to create liquibase changeset for integration tests in springboot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036222/how-to-create-liquibase-changeset-for-integration-tests-in-springboot]) I want to ensure that test data is separeted from production. Is attribute 'context' in:

```
<changeSet id="test_data_inserts" author="me" context="test">
    <sqlFile path="test_data.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />
</changeSet>
```

the only way to do that? I would like not to directly point to test-data in my master.xml databaseChangeLog under src\main\resources\config\liquibase.

Comment: did you find a solution?