# Liquibase isn't picking up a changeset from test/resources dir when running tests in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, spring-boot-test

I have the following configuration:

```
├── src
│   ├── main
...
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── db
│   │       │   └── changelog
│   │       │       ├── changes
│   │       │       │   ├── db.changelog-1.0.insert-data.xml
│   │       │       │   └── db.changelog-1.0.xml
│   │       │       ├── db.changelog-master.xml
│   │       ├── env-profiles
│   │       │   └── application.yml
...
│   └── test
...
│       └── resources
│           ├── db
│           │   └── changelog
│           │       ├── changes
│           │       │   ├── db.changelog-1.0.insert-data.xml
│           │       │   └── db.changelog-1.0.xml
│           │       ├── db.changelog-master.xml
│           └── env-profiles
│               └── application.yml
```

Both `application.yml` in `main` and `test` directories contain the same Liquibase settings:

```
spring:
...
  liquibase:
    enabled: true
    change-log: classpath:db.changelog-master.xml
```

And this is the `db.changelog-master.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
            http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
    <include file="db.changelog-1.0.xml" />
    <include file="db.changelog-1.0.insert-data.xml" />
</databaseChangeLog>
```

The difference between the changelog files in `main` and `test` directories is around the seed data for tests.

When I run my integration tests with `@SpringBootTest` I can see that the application.yml from `test` is being picked up, but Liquibase executes the changsets from the `main` dir rather than from `test`.

How to configure Spring Boot or Liquibase to make it pick the changeset from `test` directory when running tests in my current setup?

Comment: One workaround is to include the context which will trigger reading a separate changeset, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036222/how-to-create-liquibase-changeset-for-integration-tests-in-springboot/47038728 but I was wondering whether there is something simple I'm missing that prevents this setup to read changesets from resources/test dir.

Comment: your setup is quite messy. You have on classpath two files wich are on path `db/changelog/changes/db.changelog-master.xml` and probably one of them is overriding second one.  I would consider changing names of changelogs so for tests I would use sometihng like `db.changelog-master-test.xml` and also change names (or at least directory name) for changes included in `changes` folder. By that you will for sure know which changelog was loaded.